# SHA1 encryption for Minecraft client

Tags: java, minecraft, sha

I'm writing a client for Minecraft in Java. I have a lot of things working already, but the one thing that has really stumped me is how Minecraft does its authentication. I found this page

http://wiki.vg/Protocol#Handshake_.280x02.29

Which defines the protocol. As of now, the following code

```
public boolean connect(String ip, int port) {
    try {
        socket = new Socket(ip, port);
        dis = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
        dos = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
        dos.writeByte(0x02);
        dos.writeByte(0x00);
        writeString(username);
        writeString(ip);
        dos.writeInt(port);
        if (dis.readByte() != 0xFD)
            return false;
        String serverId = readString();
        byte[] publicKey = new byte[dis.readShort()];
        for (int i = 0; i < publicKey.length; i++)
            publicKey[i] = dis.readByte();
        byte[] token = new byte[dis.readShort()];
        for (int i = 0; i < token.length; i++)
            token[i] = dis.readByte();
        PublicKey serverPublicKey = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA").generatePublic(new X509EncodedKeySpec(publicKey));
        byte[] sharedSecret = new byte[16];
        new Random().nextBytes(sharedSecret);
        URL url = new URL("http://session.minecraft.net/game/joinserver.jsp?user=" + username + "&sessionId=" + session + "&serverId=" + serverId);
        url.openConnection();

        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
        return true;
    }
    catch (Exception ex) { System.out.println("Failed to login for " + username); ex.printStackTrace(); }
    return false;
}
```

is what I have. Through this code, as you can tell, I get a public key, a verification token, and generate a random shared secret. However, I don't know what to do from here. I have seen a Python implementation of this

https://github.com/ammaraskar/pyCraft/blob/master/networking/NetworkManager.py line 82

but I can't figure out how they used SHA1 to grab the serverid. I can't find an equivalent in Java. There is a authentication scheme page specific for Minecraft which more clearly defines what happens in the background here: http://wiki.vg/Protocol_Encryption

Comment: SHA1 is not an encryption algorithm. At any case, by glancing at the Python code, it looks like `serverid` is just the hex digest of the SHA1 hash computed from the `ServerID`, a shared secret and `Public Key`, and these come from `PacketListenerManager.handleFD()`, whatever that does.

Comment: handleFD() is a function inside PacketListenerManager.py that handles the login packet for Minecraft.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an excellent decompilation project for minecraft:

http://mcp.ocean-labs.de/index.php/MCP_Releases.

Have a look in `src/minecraft/net/minecraft/src/NetClientHandler.java`, and `src/minecraft/net/minecraft/src/ThreadLoginVerifier.java`.

The actual hashing is done in `src/minecraft/net/minecraft/src/CryptManager.java`, like this:

```
digestOperation("SHA-1", new byte[][] {par0Str.getBytes("ISO_8859_1"), par2SecretKey.getEncoded(), par1PublicKey.getEncoded()})
```